# Is there a way to have a string as a switch using getopts?

Tags: ksh, unix, getopts

I am seeing if there is a way for `getopts` to handle switches with strings instead of characters.

For example, I would like to supply something like this:

```
script.ksh -file1 file1.txt -file2.txt
```

Instead of:

```
script.ksh -f file1.txt -g file2.txt
```

Is this possible with unix `getopts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible with `getopts`. You must do your own parsing, e.g. with a `case` switch:

```
while (($# > 0))
do
    case "$1" in
    -file1)
        shift
        file1=$1;;
    -file2)
        shift
        file2=$1;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The external [`getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) (note no "s") can handle long options, but it has its own disadvantages.

From [BashFAQ/035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035):

> Never use getopt(1). getopt cannot handle empty arguments strings, or arguments with embedded whitespace. Please forget that it ever existed.